# Headers for Clang from VS build tools and LLVM

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang, llvm

I was experimenting with different compilers, build managers and IDEs for my new project in C++. I am using VSCode(v1.52) on a windows 10 machine. I installed VS build tools 2019 and also included C++ Clang Compiler for Windows and C++ Clang-cl for v142 build tools (x64/x86). The project uses CMake as build manager and a plug-in CMake tools have been installed as well. Setup works fine as it is now.

However, I just want to know what are the differences to include Clang compiler from VSCode build tools 2019 and from LLVM. Does Clang that comes with VSCode build tools uses its own headers or the headers from VS? I do not want to use if Clang uses headers from VS..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode build tools (C++ Clang tools for Windows) will ****link** the Clang compiler** with Microsoft implementation of the Standard Library

Also, VSCode build tools has a component called: "C++ Clang-cl for v142" that gives you the freedom of using your own Compiler/Settings

Regarding header files, on Windows you should use clang with either GCC (Open Source) or MSVC header files.

I could not find the exact source of the header files in VS Build tools. However, as said above, it will link the compiler with Microsoft STL.

To install Clang with GCC header files (Works on VsCode):

go to https://www.msys2.org/ and install mysys2

then open mysys2 terminal and copy those commands to install Clang:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-clang

pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-tools-extra
```

dont forget to add \msys64\mingw64\bin to the **SYSTEM PATH** variable

I have also made a video, with step by step: https://youtu.be/5OSO8IRlyXc